# Rotation matrix and referencials in relativity

Tags: special-relativity

I am reading the book "Gravity in a nutshell" in which the author talks about rotation in a plane and different frames, one rotated with respect to the other. The rotated frame is denoted with a prime. We are trying to find the matrix relating the differences of coordinates in both frame. It is strange, he finds  $$\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta x'\\ \Delta y'
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta  & -\sin\theta \\ 
\sin\theta  & \cos\theta 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta x\\ \Delta y
\end{bmatrix}
$$

while I found the following matrix.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta x'\\ \Delta y'
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta  & \sin\theta \\ 
-\sin\theta  & \cos\theta 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Delta x\\ \Delta y
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I am not sure what is happening (I don't think it is a matter of convention, he was using the same matrix I found until one line before the solution he found, as follows)

> Let Ms. Unprime assign the coordinates $r_P = (x, y)$ and $r_Q = (X, Y)$ to $P$ and $Q$, respectively.
> Then Mr. Prime’s coordinates $r_{P'} = (x', y')$ for $P$ and $r_{Q'} = (X', Y')$ for $Q$ are then given by $r_{P'} = \mathbf{R}(θ)r_P$ and $r_{Q'} = \mathbf{R}(θ)r_Q$. Subtracting the first equation from the second and defining $\Delta x = X − x, \Delta y = Y − y$, and the corresponding primed quantities, we obtain...

$R(θ)$ is the matrix I am using... So, what is the problem?

Comment: The second matrix is the inverse of the first one, it represents a rotation in the opposite direction

Comment: Yes i know, but it does not makes sense, because until this part he was using "my matrix", and in the subtraction he was yet using my R theta matrix, so suddenly an inverse came up in the answer?

Comment: Try to understand and distinguish between the "I rotate the objects" against to  the "I rotate the coordinates system". The matrix for one of them is the inverse for the other one. So the matrix for the rotation of a vector by an angle $\theta$ is identical  to the matrix for the rotation of the coordinates system by an angle $\boldsymbol{-}\theta$.

Comment: So, when you give me that after a rotation the new coordinates are 
$$x'=\cos30^\circ x -\sin30^\circ y$$
$$y'=\sin30^\circ x +\cos30^\circ y$$
then either you rotate the vector by an angle $\boldsymbol{+}30^\circ $ or you rotate the coordinates system by an angle $\boldsymbol{-}30^\circ$. You do choose.

Comment: I see. SO you are saying that the first is a transformation of basis. While the other is a transformation of coordinates...

Comment: I didn't see earlier your previous comment  because you didn't refer in the beginning my name "@Frobenius",  so the site didn't inform me that I had a comment. It's necessary to write in the beginning the name of the user whom it corcerns. If you post a comment under the question or answer of a user and it concerns this same user then it's not necessary to write his/her name, as we omitted yours in above comments.